# How can i set custom labels with custom values in v-slider of Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to create a custom v-slider in Vuetify 3 that shows only the values of [3,5,10,15,30,45].

I expect, that the each step displays its own proper value from the array, And,also, the max value of the slider be 45.
How can i define such a v-slider component?